# How to Download the AppBundler Jar

Tags: java, macos, jar, software-distribution, app-bundle

I would like to package a Java app into a `.app` but the java.net site is down. I can't find a mirror for the `appbundler` jar. How can I get this jar or what is another way that I can package my app with the JRE.